# Customizing FieldList views in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

How would I implement a FieldList view so that I can add rows of data, edit existing rows, and delete existing rows? This would be in another model's add or edit forms. I've been trying to read existing documentation, but I'm kinda lost. Here's a textual mockup:

```
Name          Location          Phone Number
----------------------------------------------------------------
John Doe      New York          555-123-4567     [Edit] [Delete]
Jane Thomas   New Jersey        555-987-6543     [Edit] [Delete]
Joe Bloggs    Boston            123-456-7890     [Edit] [Delete]
[Add new row]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing this without using wtforms because forms usually indicate the use of one submit button to either update or add information. Since you want multiple functionalities (and therefore multiple submit buttons), you would have to use multiple forms for each record. In order to make things less complex and reduce the messiness, you should just use a table view with buttons linking to the respective views passing record IDs as parameters.
An example of rendering such a template would be:
**views.py**

```
@app.route('/update_records/')
def update_records():
    data = model.get_all_records() #a list of dictionaries

    if data is None:
        return render_template('message.html', msg="No records exist yet")

    headers = ['Name', 'Location', 'Phone Number'] #use these headers as table headers as well as keys to accessing the dictionaries. This way you won't display the IDs to your users but can still access them for the parameter passing

    return render_template('update_records.html', data=data, headers=headers)
```

And in the template you would render all these records and against each record you would have buttons such as

```
<button onClick="location.href='{{url_for('.delete_record', id_=row['_id_'], _external=True)}}'"> Delete
    </button>
```